# Send object and additional attributes to express server via Axios and save with Mongoose

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mongoose

I'm posting a user object and a simple string to the backend via axios post and then want to store this data in MongoDB using mongoose. If I send the whole thing without the browser string, i.e. only the user object and process it in the backend, everything works. The object has all attributes except for the browser attribute. I added this later. So how can I save the user object 1:1 and also save other attributes, such as the browser attribute here? All that is actually saved is just the browser string

Function for save new User with mongoose:

```
//CREATE NEW USER
export const newUser = async (req, res, next) => {
try {
 const user = new User({ ...req.body.userD, browser: req.body.browser });

 const savedUser = await user.save();

 const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   resolve(savedUser);
 });

 myPromise.then(() => {
  res.status(200).json("User saved");
 });

 } catch (error) {
  next(err);
 }
};
```

axios post :

```
let config = {
    method: 'post',
    maxBodyLength: Infinity,
    url: 'http://localhost:3999/server/user/new',
    headers: { 
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    userD: data,
    browser:browser
};

await axios.request(config)
  .then((result) => {
    res.end(result.data)
  })
```

User Model:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
{
asn: {
  type: String,
},
city: {
  type: String,
},
continent_code: {
  type: String,
},
country: {
  type: String,
},
country_area: {
  type: Number,
},
country_calling_code: {
  type: String,
},
country_capital: {
  type: String,
},
country_code: {
  type: String,
},
country_code_iso3: {
  type: String,
},
country_name: {
  type: String,
},
country_population: {
  type: Number,
},
country_tld: {
  type: String,
},
currency: {
  type: String,
},
currency_name: {
  type: String,
},

in_eu: {
  type: Boolean,
},
ip: {
  type: String,
},
languages: {
  type: String,
},

latitude: {
  type: Number,
},
longitude: {
  type: Number,
},
network: {
  type: String,
},

org: {
  type: String,
},
postal: {
  type: Number,
},
region: {
  type: String,
},

region_code: {
  type: String,
},
timezone: {
  type: String,
},
utc_offset: {
  type: String,
},
version: {
  type: String,
},
browser: {
  type: String,
},
},
{ timestamps: true }
);

export default mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);
```

*****UPDATE*****

This is the data which is send to the express server:

> {
> "data":{
> "ip":"2003:c4:f720.xxx",
> "network":"2003:xxx",
> "version":"IPv6",
> "city":"xxxx",
> "region":"xxxx",
> "region_code":"BW",
> "country":"DE",
> "country_name":"Germany",
> "country_code":"DE",
> "country_code_iso3":"DEU",
> "country_capital":"Berlin",
> "country_tld":".de",
> "continent_code":"EU",
> "in_eu":true,
> "postal":"xxxx",
> "latitude":xxxx,
> "longitude":x.xx,
> "timezone":"Europe/Berlin",
> "utc_offset":"+0200",
> "country_calling_code":"+49",
> "currency":"EUR",
> "currency_name":"Euro",
> "languages":"de",
> "country_area":357021,
> "country_population":82927922,
> "asn":"AS3320",
> "org":"Deutsche Telekom AG"
> },
> "browser":"Browser"
> }

and this is what is saved in mongodb
[image]

Comment: do you want to update tthe browser string for a user? bit unclear

Comment: @cmgchess I call up a URL that returns all attributes except the browser attribute. I determine this using a React lib and then want to create the user and the browser attribute at once. Hope that makes it a little clearer?!

Comment: `const user = new User({ ...req.body.userD, browser: req.body.browser });` doesnt this add the browser ?

Comment: yes this adds the browser only, but not all the others

Comment: what does `userD` have

Comment: I have edit my original post

Comment: can you check if it is `const user = new User({ ...req.body.userD.data, browser: req.body.browser });`? does `req.body.userD` have a parent `data` field

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your edit part I see that you need to access the ‘data’ field and than spread…

```
const user = new User({…req.body.userD.data, browser:req.body.browser})
```